# What is `<<` and `&` in yaml mean?

Tags: yaml, hyperledger-fabric

When I review the `cryptogen`(*a fabric command*) config file . I saw there symbol.

```
Profiles:

    SampleInsecureSolo:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults  ## what is the `<<`
            Organizations:
                - *ExampleCom     ## what is the `*`
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1ExampleCom
                    - *Org2ExampleCom
```

Above there a two symbol `<<` and `*`.

```
Application: &ApplicationDefaults  # what is the `&` mean

    Organizations:
```

As you can see there is another symbol `&`.
I don't know what are there mean. I didn't get any information even by reviewing the source code (*`fabric/common/configtx/tool/configtxgen/main.go`*)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Well, those are elements of the YAML file format, which is used here to provide a configuration file for `configtxgen`. The "&" sign mean anchor and "*" reference to the anchor, this is basically used to avoid duplication, for example:

```
person: &person
    name: "John Doe"

employee: &employee
    << : *person
    salary : 5000
```

will reuse fields of person and has similar meaning as:

```
employee: &employee
    name   : "John Doe"
    salary : 5000
```

another example is simply reusing value:

```
key1: &key some very common value

key2: *key
```

equivalent to:

```
key1: some very common value

key2: some very common value
```

Since `abric/common/configtx/tool/configtxgen/main.go` uses of the shelf YAML parser you won't find any reference to these symbols in `configtxgen` related code. I would suggest to read a bit more about [YAML file format](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/).

Comment: Tried your ': << *person' line in https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and it failed to compile. That line should be '<< : *person' though. And << need to indent with salary on next line.

Comment: @Wappenull: I can confirm your fix and have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Quick question, is it possible to create a list using multiple references ? if L1 is -a -b -c and L2 is -d -e -f, can I create L3 by using *l1a & l2a , anchors to L1 and L2 respectively to create -a -b -c -d -e -f ?

Comment: `*` and `&` are described clearly in the [yaml spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/). The confusing part is `<<:` which isn't.

Answer (score 2):

in yaml if data is like

```
user: &userId '123'
username: *userId
```

```
equivalent yml is
user: '123'
username: '123'

or

equivalent json will is
{
    "user": "123",
    "username": "123"
}
```

so it basically allows to reuse data, you can also try with array instead of single value like 123

try converting below yml to json using any yml to json online converter

```
users: &users
  k1: v1
  k2: v2
  
usernames: *users
```